# redirecting with htaccess while avoiding search engine penalty

Tags: apache, .htaccess, seo

I have a website that has been up for about 2 years now, it gained some search engine reputation over the time, and now I'm interested in using htaccess on it,
to rename things such as:

/index.php?act=Login
to simply 
/Login

Now the problem is, that search engines will see both urls, and the login page is far from being the only url I will rename.
Which pretty much means that my entire website will have double the urls it has now,
What can I do to prevent it from causing damage to the SEO?

Is there some line of htaccess code I could use to redirect the old pages to the new ones as well? (I'm not even sure if that'll solve the SEO issue)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bottom line is to use `R=301` (**moved permanently**) to inform search engines about your new URLs. For ex have your .htaccess code like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# external redirect using R=301 to /login from /index.php?act=Login
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(index\.php/?|)\?act=login(&|\s) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /login? [R=301,L]

# internal forward from /login to /index.php?act=Login
RewriteRule ^login/?$ index.php?act=login [L,QSA,NC]
```

With `R=301` directive search engines will eventually start caching your new URI scheme instead of the old ones.

Comment: Thank you for answering so fast! :) but uhm, could you please add some explanation on what each line does? I'll need to rewrite a lot of pages and I'm not entirely sure what your code does, thanks again!

Comment: @Don I have added some comments before both rules now. Let me know if something is not clear and I will happily add that.

Comment: Thanks! it does work and the comments are easy to understand, I'm a bit curious though, why does it also let login?act=Login work? I tried to edit it but couldnt get to stop that

Comment: The first rule should force `/index.php?act=Login` into `/login`. And the 2nd one would forward `/login` to `/index.php?act=login`. However 2nd one is not restricting anything in query string hence `/login?foo=bar` will also forward to `/index.php?foo=bar&act=login`. If you want to disallow query string in `/login` forward rule then add `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^$` before 2nd RewriteRule.

Comment: Works like a charm :) and uhmm.. last question sorry for being so annoying haha, Is it possible to go for renaming /?act=login other than /index.php?act=login?

Comment: You're welcome. In your httpd.comf have a line like this: `DirectoryIndex index.html index.php index.htm` and then `/?act=login` will be equivalent to `/index.php?act=login`. That will require a minor edit in 1st rule (see my last edit).

Comment: I don't think I have access to the httpd file as I'm hosting my site on a shared web hosting service

Comment: In that case `DirectoryIndex` entry for `index.php` might still be there. Did you try entering `/?act=login` URI in the browser?

Comment: Yes, it works fine, by the way, do I have to use FollowSymlinks? the server I'm hosting it on sais: Option FollowSymlinks not allowed here

Comment: Using FollowSymlinks is not required so you can leave it out if your server doesn't allow you.

Comment: Eh I don't know if I'll use it for now, I thought it worked as I tried it on my local xampp server, it redirected the url and all, but now when I actually upload it the browser crashes and tells me that theres some redirecting loop, maybe I'll just leave it for now hehe

Comment: Oops that was my mistake, sorry about that. I just corrected it and tested it. It should work now.