# htacces redirect for SEO friendly URLs

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have my htaccess file setup, so that the pages remove extensions. Now, I am trying to make the pages that transfer variables, into SEO friendly urls ... so, for example...

http://www.example.com/art-gallery?page=2 ... which is actually "art-gallery.php?page=2", would turn into... http://www.example.com/art-gallery/page/2

Or... http://www.example.com/art-piece?id=3 ...would go to... http://www.example.com/art-piece/id/3

... and so on ...

I have alot in my htaccess file, and am not sure how to do the above (there are plenty of tutorials on going from www.example.com/index.php?page=2 to www.example.com/page/2/ but none that do exactly what I need). Ideally, I'd like to be able to do this for all similar pages...

```
# enable the rewrite engine
RewriteEngine On
# Set your root directory
  RewriteBase /

# Force www:
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,R=301,NC]

# Remove the .php extension
  RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET\ (.*)\.php\ HTTP
  RewriteRule (.*)\.php$ $1 [R=301]

# Remove index and reference the directory
  RewriteRule (.*)/index$ $1/ [R=301]

# Remove trailing slash if not a directory
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /$
  RewriteRule (.*)/ $1 [R=301]

# Forward request to html file, **but don't redirect (bot friendly)**
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
  RewriteRule (.*) $1\.php [L]

# Disable Directory Browsing
  Options -Indexes

# Disable Hotlinking of Images 
# with forbidden or custom image option
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?example.com [NC]
  RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?google.com [NC]
  RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ – [NC,F,L] 

# Protect htaccess File
  <files ~ "^.*\.([Hh][Tt][Aa])">
  order allow,deny
  deny from all
  satisfy all
  </files>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can transfer parameters with the variable `QUERY_STRING`.
Consider the following rule:

```
RewriteRule ^index.html index.php?%{QUERY_STRING}&m=main&a=index
```

This rule would transform

```
index.html?something=value
```

into

```
index.php?something=value&m=main&a=index
```

Comment: This answer doesn't result in SEO friendly urls. I need something that takes... filename.html?something=value and changes it to filename/something/value.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [RewriteEngine](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html).

You could also use a 301 redirect either alone or in conjunction with the RewriteEngine to redirect SEs.

Generally, though redirecting SEs to a different page than what users will see is not a good practice, and may result in your pagerank decreasing. Instead, try migrating all your pages to the second URL format, and consider using 301 redirects to help the transition.

**Generally:** Use 301 redirects for SE-friendly page changes. See this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12244657/redirecting-with-htaccess-while-avoiding-search-engine-penalty) for additional reference.

Comment: I was told that 301 Redirects wont work with URLs that pass variables (i.e. art-piece?page=1), and told to use a RewriteRule for those kinds of urls. Also, I have TONS of pages in the art-gallery?page=# (where # could be any number). So, that would be ALOT of redirects. When you say "migrating all your pages to the second URL format ... not sure what you mean, nor how to do it...

Comment: You should be able to use a RegExp substitution rule to modify your URL in a way that would give you the SEO friendly URLS. Try experimenting with the RewriteEngine some more.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert this rule **just before Forward request to html file** rule:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/])/([^/])/([^/])/?$ $1.php?$2=$3 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: These type of comments are pretty much useless since it doesn't tell anything about what you tried and what problem are you getting.

Answer (score 0):

This is quite old but why not do the following:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^?]*) index.php?route=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Then in your index.php you can handle it like such;

```
if (isset($_GET['route'])) {
   $route = explode('/', $_GET['route']);
   if (iconv_strlen((end($parts)), 'UTF-8') == 0) {
       array_pop($parts);
   }
}
```

From here your main level would be handled with $route[0], second level $route[1]

For example;

```
 http://example.com/art-gallery/2
```

$route[0] would equal 'art-gallery'
$route[1] would equal '2'